# Detect text dragged from one application into the web browser?

Tags: javascript, events

I would like to be able to handle text being dragged from one application into my web app. I've looked up examples for the `onDragDrop` event but not found anything useful. At the moment I'm experimenting with dropping the text onto a `<textarea>` so I can easily recover the dropped text.

Has anyone had any experience doing this?

Edit (for clarification): I don't mind what element I drop on to as long as I can get the text that's dropped. I won't be dropping anything other than text.

Comment: Where u want to drag and drop (textbox, div) and what u want to drag (text, image??) , please explain a bit more and we could visualize your need!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You´re maybe looking for the ondrop event of HTML5

Comment: I want to keep this as backward compatible as I can so can't use HTML 5 stuff I'm afraid.